# Is this function which shows infinite concussion near $0$ Hölder continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

*Define* $f:\left(0,+\infty \right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x)=x\cos \frac{1}{x}$$

*Is $f$ Hölder continuous?*

I found it uniformly continuous because it is continuous in the interval $(0,1] $ and lipschitz continuous in the interval $ \left[ 1,+\infty \right)$

> *In fact, we can define $f(0)=0$, so $f$ is continuous in the interval $[0,1]$  .Then it makes sense.*

I wonder whether this function which shows infinite concussion near $0$ is Hölder continuous. But I found it hard to prove or disprove. 
Any ideas fot that? Thanks a lot!

**Added**: I guess this function is Hölder continuous, specificly I guess: $$f \in C^{0.5}\left[0,+\infty\right)$$
That's because when finding a counter-example that proves $f$ not Hölder continuous, given $a_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$ I tried to get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n\cos \frac{1}{a_n}-b_n\cos\frac{1}{b_n}}{(a_n-b_n)^\alpha}=+\infty$ but it's not true when $\alpha=0.5$.

Comment: The function you used is uniformly continuous, although not for the reason you gave, with 1/x being a counterexample.

Comment: We can define $f(0)=0$ so it's continuous in the interval $[0,1]$ and then it's uniformly continuous in the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: Would you consider the Weierstrass function to be an example? According to Wikipedia, it is Holder continuous under certain conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: Sorry, I don't figure out whether this function can be changed into the that Weierstrass function form. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Actually I misread your question and thought you were just looking for an example of a highly oscillatory function that is Holder continuous.  Let me think about this particular function if I can get some time.